# How to sort a multidimensional list based on multiple keys?

Tags: python, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following list.

`initial =[('fanitst', 257.72815, 43.42322), ('st', 47.82522, 51.149788), ('hird', 572.8713, 60.59974), ('irces', 710.9375, 61.953125), ('income', 35.546875, 111.71875), ('tax', 155.39062, 112.734375), ('department', 213.42479, 111.97105), ('govt', 577.8906, 116.796875), ('of', 690.625, 116.796875), ('india', 742.4219, 116.796875), ('hitu', 56.875, 169.60938), ('biswas', 135.0781, 169.60936), ('biswas', 197.03125, 243.75), ('haridas', 54.84375, 244.76562), ('in', 648.0486, 272.82794), ('n', 726.6486, 303.17294), ('051031920', 51.569546, 320.44266), ('number', 283.35938, 355.46875), ('account', 181.64876, 357.539), ('permanent', 52.67427, 359.5602), ('czkpb5432z', 53.38768, 399.7318), ('s', 842.3438, 427.73975), ('biswas', 125.9375, 468.20312), ('hilu', 59.921875, 469.21875), ('signature', 50.868423, 528.95844)]`

Every item is basically a tuple of a word, it's x-coordinate and it's y-coordinate.

I have to arrange them so the output looks like following. It is done by

1. grouping all the words whose y-coordinates have values close to each other(e.g. less than 5).
2. Then the words coming in the same line should be sorted on the basis of their x-coordinates.

How should I do this 2nd part?

```
fanitst
st
hird irces
income tax department govt of india
hitu biswas
haridas biswas
in
n
051031920
permanent account number 
czkpb5432z
s
biswas hilu
```

Currently I am getting the following output.

```
fanitst
st
hird irces
income tax department govt of india
hitu biswas
biswas haridas
in
n
051031920
number account permanent
czkpb5432z
s
biswas hilu
```

The code I wrote to reach here is following.

```
for i in range(len(initial)-1):
    if abs(initial[i][2] - initial[i+1][2]) < 5:     
        print(initial[i][0], end=" ")
    else:
        print(initial[i][0])
```

If I can store each line of the output in a separate list , I think I can work my way forward from there. However, I can't think of a way to store each line in a different list. Each time the number of lists will be different so I don't know how many lists we would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
initial =[('fanitst', 257.72815, 43.42322), ('st', 47.82522, 51.149788), ('hird', 572.8713, 60.59974), ('irces', 710.9375, 61.953125), ('income', 35.546875, 111.71875), ('tax', 155.39062, 112.734375), ('department', 213.42479, 111.97105), ('govt', 577.8906, 116.796875), ('of', 690.625, 116.796875), ('india', 742.4219, 116.796875), ('hitu', 56.875, 169.60938), ('biswas', 135.0781, 169.60936), ('biswas', 197.03125, 243.75), ('haridas', 54.84375, 244.76562), ('in', 648.0486, 272.82794), ('n', 726.6486, 303.17294), ('051031920', 51.569546, 320.44266), ('number', 283.35938, 355.46875), ('account', 181.64876, 357.539), ('permanent', 52.67427, 359.5602), ('czkpb5432z', 53.38768, 399.7318), ('s', 842.3438, 427.73975), ('biswas', 125.9375, 468.20312), ('hilu', 59.921875, 469.21875), ('signature', 50.868423, 528.95844)]

def group(lst):
    new = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        if i == 0 or (not (abs(lst[i][2] - lst[i-1][2]) < 5)):
            new.append([])
        new[-1].append(lst[i])
        i += 1

    return new

def sort(lst):
    for row in lst:
        row.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

lst = group(initial)
sort(lst)
print('\n'.join(' '.join(y[0] for y in x) for x in lst))
```

Output:

```
fanitst
st
hird irces
income tax department govt of india
hitu biswas
haridas biswas
in
n
051031920
permanent account number
czkpb5432z
s
hilu biswas
signature
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot !